# Debezium connector starts but returns no tables from CDC

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using SQL Server connector and the logs show `Locking captured tables []` - no tables are captured. I've verified my schema, table, and database. I've tried the following, all with topics pre-created.. (also specify all variables from Debezium SQL docs)

- "table.include.list" : "testTable" && "schema.include.list": "dbo"
- "table.include.list" : "dbo.testTable" && "schema.include.list": "dbo"
- "table.include.list" : "DBNAME.dbo.testTable" && "schema.include.list": "dbo"
- "table.include.list" : "DBNAME.dbo.testTable"
- "table.include.list" : "dbo.testTable"

Running out of ideas, and no data is captured.. there are thousands of records in the table and its takes ~25min to redeploy docker and cycle thru for tests

```
2022-06-09T01:28:35.036573+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-09 01:28:35,036] INFO Snapshot step 3 - Locking captured tables [] (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource)
2022-06-09T01:28:35.036779+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-09 01:28:35,036] INFO Setting locking timeout to 10 s (io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource)
2022-06-09T01:28:35.069576+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-09 01:28:35,066] INFO Executing schema locking (io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource)
2022-06-09T01:28:35.069586+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-09 01:28:35,066] INFO Snapshot step 4 - Determining snapshot offset (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource)
2022-06-09T01:28:35.080765+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-09 01:28:35,080] INFO Snapshot step 5 - Reading structure of captured tables (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource)
2022-06-09T01:28:35.081107+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-09 01:28:35,081] INFO Snapshot step 6 - Persisting schema history (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource)
2022-06-09T01:28:35.087858+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-09 01:28:35,087] INFO Schema locks released. (io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource)
2022-06-09T01:28:35.087894+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-09 01:28:35,087] INFO Snapshot step 7 - Snapshotting data (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource)
2022-06-09T01:28:35.088336+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-09 01:28:35,088] INFO Snapshotting contents of 0 tables while still in transaction (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource)
2022-06-09T01:28:35.098247+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-09 01:28:35,098] INFO Snapshot - Final stage (io.debezium.pipeline.source.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource)
2022-06-09T01:28:35.104830+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-09 01:28:35,104] INFO Removing locking timeout (io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource)
2022-06-09T01:28:35.118107+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-09 01:28:35,118] INFO Snapshot ended with SnapshotResult [status=COMPLETED, offset=SqlServerOffsetContext [sourceInfoSchema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.Source:STRUCT}, sourceInfo=SourceInfo [serverName=heroku_connect, changeLsn=NULL, commitLsn=001d23f3:00016cc0:0001, eventSerialNo=null, snapshot=FALSE, sourceTime=null], snapshotCompleted=true, eventSerialNo=1]] (io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator)
2022-06-09T01:28:35.118780+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-09 01:28:35,118] WARN After applying the include/exclude list filters, no changes will be captured. Please check your configuration! (io.debezium.relational.RelationalDatabaseSchema)
```

Comment: Have you enabled CDC in the target database yet? e.g.: `use MyDB; EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db;` How did you enable CDC on `dbo.testTable`? If you didn't specify a valid `@role_name` parameter then only members of the `sysadmin` role or `db_owner` role have access to the change table.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - thanks for the tips, but yes, I have. Turned out to be a typo. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be a typo, all works as expected. Make sure to **only use**

`table.include.list: .*tablename` or specify both a schema and table like `table.include.list: <schemaname>.<fulltablename>`